# The best way to create cronjob automatically? (If it is possible)

Tags: php, rss, cron, feed

i'm wondering if it is possible to automatically create cronjob everytime i get a link to a feed rss on my website, to keep track of every post of the post inside those feed rss.

And i'm wondering also if there is a better solution instead of create a cronjob for each feed rss.

(i already know how to get post from feed, i just want to know if and how its possible to do that thing with cronjob)

Currently i've this table on db:

```
---------------------
|      FEED_RSS     |
|-------------------|
|id | title | link  |
|-------------------|
| 1 | feed1 | link1 |
| 2 | feed2 | link2 |
| 3 | feed3 | link3 |
| 4 | feed4 | link4 |
```

Those values ar recorded by an input text from users.

So, is a good solution to create multiple cronjob? And first of all, can i do that dinamically for each record of the database? if yes...how should i do that?

(i already know how to get post from feed, i just want to know if and how its possible to do that thing with cronjob)

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting package? I think there is a limit to the number of cron jobs you can schedule.

Comment: Why would you need a cronjob for every RSS feed? Just one cronjob seems sufficient.

Comment: nope, i'm on a personal vps, with unlimited cron jobs permission i guess, anyway if it's not i'll change to something with unlimited cronjob option

Comment: @Daan this is one of my problem, i think multiple will be faster, am i right? Because i've to keep track of a lot (million or billion) of data so i need to keep track of everyone to let the users have a complete in anytime

Answer (score 2):

You can do this automatically by using a Queue messaging system, like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), and every time you have a new insertion in database, you send a message to RabbitMQ, and you need a consumer to do the job from your crontab.

But maybe it's a too big solution.

Comment: I'm thinking about that: everytime a user open a feed i launch a function that find if there are new post from that feed, and if it isn't already recorded on db i record it and set a value like "valued" = 1, then use a cronjob for every feed rss that isn't already valued since a range of time, i think i will use less resource and it will be faster, what do you think?

Comment: You won't get RSS data which are updated because normally RSS feeds will get updated every x hours or x days. For the most robust solution you'll need a cronjob and a queuing system. The OP also needs to save some kind of updated_date in the database.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what do you want to do. What does user do and what do you record in database, and what your cronjob are actually doing?